# SQL Server sub query tutorial & material

Tags: sql

I am studying SQL Server and got stuck with the sub query syntax. Could someone show me some sites, links, where i could study them please?

Answer (score 1):

The subquery is a valuable concept to understand. Creative use of a subquery allows the desired results to be returned in a single T-SQL statement, and helps avoid the use of temporary tables and cursors to solve complicated selection criteria. In addition, depending on the query, a subquery might improve performance by reducing the number of records that SQL Server needs to process.

Easy one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575.aspx

Detailed one:

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/MS-SQL-Server/Subqueries-and-Query-Expressions/

Answer (score 0):

Introductory tutorials:

http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm

http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2001/07/26/aboutSQL.html